# How to draw that on illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am wondering how to do that like in a simple way for example using repeat or similar . I am traying to find the math behind rotating ovals and similar but i dont get the point...

can anyone help with some clue?

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried? I cannot think of an easy way to do exactly this in Illustrator. The 3D modeling tools in Illustrator is very rudimentary. This would be an easier task to do in a 3D modeling program like Blender.

Comment: yeah , i am not trying to design it on #D , just flat version line by line on illustrator.

You know , vector style, simple flat. For example just drawing the 6 color lines and leave space between them

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a tutorial, just the basic steps of how you could go about it, to get something similar.

1. Take the photo into Photoshop, and perspective distort it to make it into a circle, as close as you can get.
2. Copy and paste it in Illustrator, add guides at the centre and draw two circles to match the inner and outer ones of the object, then draw curves that intersect to make the shapes
3. Group and rotate these 60°, and copy all round the circle
4. Use the shape builder to make the pieces, and colour them by adding fills and remove the strokes

Here's a very rough example. I'm pretty sure if you spend more time on it, you could improve it.

[image]click to see larger

Obviously, you could then distort it by squishing it afterwards, back into an ellipse.

Comment: thanks for your reply!

I know this way manually with the pen , but as you can see here the geometry is not  good , cos you can handle it properly ...

i am looking a way to do it via auto repeat curve lines, to get 100% perfect symetry

Comment: @omme My answer already tells you how to auto repeat the curves in step 3. A shape like this will have perfect rotational symmetry, if you rotate the curves at 60 degree increments around the centre of the two circles.  Note: the shown example is only a very rough demonstration of the technique. If you are having difficult creating nice smooth curves, you could use the Curvature Tool instead of the Pen Tool. You could also use ellipses rotated around the same centre.

Comment: thanks sir!! i really appreciate your time